# What do the smaller notes in the Treble Clef indicate?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

[image: Misocal score where some note heads are smaller than the majority]

This is piano sheet music for "I Will Follow You Into The Dark" by Death Cab for Cutie. I've been trying to search for what these notes mean. Do I play them with the left hand? Not play them? Are they optional? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This small pitch just means that it's an optional pitch to play. You *definitely* have to play the D, but you could also play D and F. (But you'll never play only F.) You can play this pitch with either the left or right hand.

The musical term is *ossia*, which is Italian for "alternatively." Oftentimes *ossia* parts are written on a different staff:

[image]

But in your case, since it's just a single note, they wrote it slightly smaller.

These smaller notes are *not* to be confused with the small pitches discussed in [Small notes on the staff](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/47734/small-notes-on-the-staff). The small notes there are grace notes, which are completely different.

Comment: Just to make things clear since you said "alternatively," I can play the D **or** the F in the first measure? Or is it an option to play both?

Comment: @AndreAngelo It seems to me it's either D&F or just D. Note (no pun intended) that only the F is smaller

Comment: @AndreAngelo Very good question, and JAD is right on. I'll edit to make that more obvious.

Comment: ...and on orchestral sheet music, the small notes could mean "this is what you'll hear by another instrument"...

Comment: @elliotsvensson: All the cue notes I've notivced would have small stems of their own, rather merely having small note heads sharing the stem with performed notes.